# How do i get a bundle object values to another application (sms)?

Tags: android

I am working on an application that gets the value from an edittext and stores it in a string (bundle) , the bundle is passed to next activity.
These values are to be sent as a sms.
**What i want to know is how to put the values object in smsintent with sms_body**. Please help me out.

**Code for storing values in bundle**

```
 long mobile = Long.parseLong(mobilenumber);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                b.putLong("mobilenumber", mobile);
                Intent in = new Intent(SendnumActivity.this, SenderActivity.class);

                in.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    });
    };
public void initializeEditTexts() { 
number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
 } 
public void getDataFromForm() { 
mobilenumber = number.getText().toString(); 
}
```

**Code for sending message**

```
public void opensms(){
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","");
    startActivity(smsIntent);

}
```

Comment: Can you add your bundle code? Need to know the key to answer this question

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in **Activity**:

Activity **Main**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,SendMessage.class);
i.putExtra("mobilenumber", "123456789");
i.putExtra("text", "Hello");
i.putExtra("arg3", "1");
...
i.putExtra("arg10", "test");
context.startActivity(i);
```

Activity **SMS**:

```
String mn = intent.getStringExtra("mobilenumber");
String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");
```

Doing this in **Fragment**:

Activity **Main**:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("mobilenumber", "123456789");
args.putString("text", "Hello");
args.putString("arg3", "Hello");
args.putString("arg4", "Hello");
...
args.putString("arg10", "Hello");
```

Fragment **SMS**:

```
String mn = getArguments().getString("mobilenumber");
String text = getArguments().getString("text");
```

---

Update as per comment.

Also, you can use

```
putStringArray(String key, String[] value)
```

Bundle or Intent Args are basically Key / Value pairs, but you cannot put an object. If you really need to send object to the next activity. You can use Gson to convert an object to a JSONObject and use the resultant string to pass as string to the next activity/fragment.

```
activity.putExtra("ObjJson", new Gson().toJson(myobject));
```

Comment: If i have to store more than 10 values what do i do?

Comment: Keep adding putExtra (Activity) or putString/Int in Bundle (for Fragment)

Comment: Can you please help me, by implementing your idea in my code